# PostAsJsonAsync Deep Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using PostAsJsonAsync to pass a parameter to a web api service like so

```
public T Save<T>(string url, T item) where T : class
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = _dbServiceUriProvider.GetUri();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, item).Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new DbServiceException("Error in DbServiceDataSaver:\r\n" + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
            T returnVar = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            return returnVar;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this is only serializing the object I'm passing and not any child objects. For example if I had a class Foo that had a member of HashSet<Bar> the Bars aren't getting serialized. Is this because HashSets can't be serialized or is something else going on here?

Comment: `HashSet<T>` can be serialized. That isn't the problem. What does your `T item` look like, and what is the output JSON you receive?

Comment: How do I view the JSON, do I need to use Fiddler or something?

Comment: That's a possibility, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Serializable attribute on class level and datamember on properties level it will work for you or use json.serializeObjectmethod.
and for view the json data don't need fiddler just install one plugin named json viewer it will display your data in json format on browser itself.
[https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/jsonview/][1]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had [DataMember] attributes on my classes for only some of the properties so only those properties were getting serialized